# What is the difference between Collection and AbstractCollection in Java?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, abstract-class

Edit: what i am actually meant to ask about is why do we need an abstract class, a hash class, etc implementing interfaces like map, set and collection?? What is the difference between those (abstractmap, hashmap, map) and why do they need to be interfaces?

Comment: `AbstractCollection` implements most of the methods. `Collection`, being an interface, don't. Are you actually try to ask why there is an interface at all, and not just the `AbstractCollection`? That's a totally different question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to implement a collection, it is easier to extend `AbstractCollection` which has already some methods of `Collection` implemented, than to implement the whole `Collection` interface.

From [documentation of AbstractCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html):

> This class provides a skeletal implementation of the Collection interface, to minimize the effort required to implement this interface.